# SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: c#, sql, exception, ado.net, connection-string

I'm taking some basic lessons and I'm trying the simplest example possible but I'm getting a SQL exception during the reader execution.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ... Incorrect syntax near '='.

Here's the core of the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDBFileName=C:\\Users\\james\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Day8_6\\Database1.mdf;";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connectionString, connection);

                connection.Open();

                // *** ERROR ON FOLLOWING LINE
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{1}\t{2}", reader[1], reader[2]);
                }

                connection.Close();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Suggetions? Thank you!

Comment: ``SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connectionString, connection);
```

needs to be:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
```

Comment: Facepalm... Thank you! I've been staring past it for the last 30 minutes! It always helps to have other's eyes on the code.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing connection string in `SqlCommand` contructor instead of `sql` query:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
```